# For every natural number $n$, prove that $n^n > 1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdots (2n-1)$.

Tags: inequality

> For every natural number $n$, prove that $n^n > 1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdots (2n-1)$.

I tried solving this by assuming that the above equation is true for $n$ and tried proving it is also true for $n+1$, but did not reach anywhere.

Comment: Hint: Try using mathematical induction.

Comment: This is actually false (try $n=1$). Is the greater than symbol supposed to be greater than or equal to?

Comment: Use AM-GM. Easier than induction. And yes, it is only true for $n>1.$

Comment: If you insist on using induction (or the question requires it) the binomial theorem may be of help.

Comment: @PendronatorI think it means for all n>1.

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1897775/prove-that-nn1-times3-times5-times7-times-dots-times2n-1) answer your question? [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120442/please-help-me-prove-by-induction-that-nn1-cdot3-cdot5-cdot-ldots-cdot2n-1) has even more answers, mostly by induction. Found using Approach0.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, try AM-GM:
$$n = \frac{1+3+5+\dots+(2n-1)}n \geqslant \sqrt[n]{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots(2n-1)}$$

Equality is possible iff $n=1$.

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate on the idea of using binomial theorem, for $n\ge 2$:

$$(n+1)^{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom {n+1}k1^kn^{n+1-k}\ge\binom {n+1}0n^{n+1}+\binom {n+1}1n^n=(2n+1)n^n$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Pair off factors starting from the beginning and the end of the second product, and use the identity $n^2>n^2-k^2=(n-k)(n+k)$.

Answer (score 2):

If
$n^n > 1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdots (2n-1)
=\prod_{k=1}^n (2k-1)
$
then
we want to show that
$(n+1)^{n+1}
\gt\prod_{k=1}^{n+1} (2k-1)
$.

For $n=2$,
this is
$2^2 > 1\cdot3$
which is true.

By the induction hypothesis,
$\prod_{k=1}^{n+1} (2k-1)
=(2n+1)\prod_{k=1}^{n} (2k-1)
\lt (2n+1)n^n
$

so we want
$(2n+1)n^n
\le (n+1)^{n+1}
$

or
$2n+1
\le (n+1)(1+1/n)^n
$

or
$(1+1/n)^n
\ge \dfrac{2n+1}{n+1}
=2-\dfrac1{n+1}
$.

By Bernoulli's inequality,
$(1+1/n)^n > 2$
and we are done.

Comment: You just need Bernoulli’s inequality: $(1+1/n)^n\ge 1+n(1/n)=2$

Comment: I realized that later but decided to leave it as is.

Comment: What the heck. I made the change.

Answer (score 2):

Here's two ways to prove that
$$n^n\geq \frac{(2n)!}{2^n n!}$$

First way, by induction:

For $n=1$, $1^1=1$ so the posited inequality holds true. For $n=2$, $2^2>3$, which is also true. For an arbitrary natural number $n=m$ assume that the inequality holds true.
Then for $n=m+1$ it holds that
$$(m+1)^{m+1}=m\left(1+\frac{1}{m}\right)^{m+1}m^m>m\left(1+\frac{1}{m}\right)^{m+1}1\cdot3...(2m-1)$$
so it suffices to show that $m\left(1+\frac{1}{m}\right)^{m+1}>2m+1$. Indeed if we use the inequality $(1+x)^a\geq 1+ax$ on the quantity in parentheses, we obtain
$$m\left(1+\frac{1}{m}\right)^{m+1}>m\left(1+\frac{m+1}{m}\right)=2m+1$$
and we are done!

Second way:

Group each term starting from the end with a term starting from the beginning. By virtue of this we can write

$$\frac{(2n)!}{2^n n!}=\prod_{i=1}^{n/2}i(2n-i)~,~ n=2k$$
$$\frac{(2n)!}{2^n n!}=n\prod_{i=1}^{(n-1)/2}i(2n-i)~,~ n=2k+1$$
or more succinctly
$$\frac{(2n)!}{2^n n!}=n^{2\{n/2\}}\prod_{i=1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}i(2n-i)$$
One can easily show however that
$$(x-n)^2\geq 0\iff x(2n-x)\leq n^2, x\in \mathbb{R}$$
Therefore by applying this formula to each term we get
$$\frac{(2n)!}{2^n n!}\leq n^{2\lfloor n/2 \rfloor+2\{n/2\}}=n^{2\frac{n}{2}}=n^n$$
and this completes the proof.